# How to redesign/fix this program to allow encapsulation?

Tags: c++, encapsulation

I asked this question initially on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/225079/simple-first-come-first-serve-scheduling-simulator). Because of negative reception there (completely my fault), I think this would be the right place to ask. I am copying the exact same question here that I asked there (with some minor edits).

My goal is to write a CPU Scheduling Simulator in C++ using the STL features as far as possible. So far, I have only written the code for FCFS and have not provided any input method.

What sticks out most to me is the definition of the process class. The way I have designed the program, there is very poor encapsulation. Looking at my current situation, I have only two solutions in mind:

1. Make all data members private. Provide accessors for PID, Arrival Time and Burst Time and mutators for the rest. However, I fear this would make my code bloated and also the use of mutators would only break encapsulation.
2. Make `FCFS()`, `displayResult()` and any other algorithms that I add `friend`s of the `process` class. This allows me to control the encapsulation to a certain extent so I like this one.

Another thing I tried to do was make the PID, Arrival Time and Burst Time variables `const` and public. This allowed algorithms to read their values but not modify them. However, the code wouldn't compile because `const` members aren't default assignable.

I would like suggestions as to how I can solve the above mentioned problem and also how I can use the STL more effectively to make my code more expressive.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>

constexpr int notYetComputed = std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max();

struct process 
{
    unsigned int m_procId;
    unsigned int m_arrivalTime;
    unsigned int m_burstTime;

    unsigned int m_responseTime;
    unsigned int m_completionTime;
    unsigned int m_turnaroundTime;
    unsigned int m_waitingTime;

    process(unsigned int pid, unsigned int at, unsigned int bt)
        : m_procId {pid}, m_arrivalTime {at}, m_burstTime {bt}
    {
        m_waitingTime = m_turnaroundTime = m_completionTime = m_responseTime = notYetComputed;
    }
};

void displayResult(const std::vector<process>& procs)
{
    for(auto& x : procs)
        std::cout << "PID: " << x.m_procId << ", "
            << "Waiting Time: " << x.m_waitingTime << ", "
            << "Turnaround Time: " << x.m_turnaroundTime << ", "
            << "Response Time: " << x.m_responseTime << ", "
            << "Completion Time: " << x.m_completionTime << "\n";
}
void FCFS(std::vector<process>& procList)
{
    //Sort based on arrival order. Use PID in case of same arrival time.
    auto arrivalOrder = [] (const process& p1, const process& p2) {
        if(p1.m_arrivalTime < p2.m_arrivalTime) return true;
        if(p1.m_arrivalTime == p2.m_arrivalTime) return (p1.m_procId < p2.m_procId);
        return false;
    };
    std::sort(procList.begin(), procList.end(), arrivalOrder);

    unsigned int clock {0};
    auto computeResult = [&clock] (process& pr) {
        pr.m_responseTime = clock - pr.m_arrivalTime;
        pr.m_waitingTime = (pr.m_turnaroundTime = 
            (pr.m_completionTime = (clock += pr.m_burstTime)) - pr.m_arrivalTime)
            - pr.m_burstTime;
    };

    std::for_each(procList.begin(), procList.end(), computeResult);

}

int main()
{   
    std::vector<process> procs {{0,0,5}, {1,1,3}, {2,2,8}, {3,3,6}};

    FCFS(procs);

    //Sort based on PID before showing result
    std::sort(procs.begin(), procs.end(), 
        [](const process& p1, const process& p2) {
            return p1.m_procId < p2.m_procId;
    });

    displayResult(procs);
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I intend to add more scheduling algorithms in the future. So I prefer answers along Jarod42's line of thought. I can't really make algorithm-specific code part of the `process` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your process class contains both input and output members.

I would split them (Names I use should probably be improved) to be explicit about the flow (and we can get rid of `notYetComputed` which seems to be an hack for me):

```
struct process_input
{
    unsigned int m_procId;
    unsigned int m_arrivalTime;
    unsigned int m_burstTime;
};

struct process_ouput
{
    unsigned int m_responseTime;
    unsigned int m_completionTime;
    unsigned int m_turnaroundTime;
    unsigned int m_waitingTime;
};

struct process
{
    process_input m_input;
    process_output m_output;
};
```

`FCFS` would show the flow, so `std::vector<process> FCFS(std::vector<process_input> inputs)`

With some style changes, it becomes:

```
std::vector<process> FCFS(std::vector<process_input> inputs)
{
    // Sort based on arrival order. Use PID in case of same arrival time.
    auto proj = [](const process_input& p){ return std::tie(p.m_arrivalTime, p.m_procId); };
    auto compare = [&] (const process& lhs, const process& rhs) {
        return proj(lhs) < proj(rhs);
    };
    std::sort(inputs.begin(), inputs.end(), compare);

    std::vector<process> res;
    res.reserve(inputs.size());
    unsigned int clock {0};

    auto computeOutput = [] (const process_input& pr, unsigned int& clock) {
        process_ouput res;

        res.m_responseTime = clock - pr.m_arrivalTime;
        clock += pr.m_burstTime;
        res.m_completionTime = clock;
        res.m_turnaroundTime = res.m_completionTime - pr.m_arrivalTime;
        res.m_waitingTime = res.m_turnaroundTime - pr.m_burstTime;
        return res;
    };

    for (auto& input : inputs) {
        res.push_back({input, computeOutput(input, clock)});
    }
    return res;
}
```

That changes `main` to:

```
int main()
{   
    std::vector<process> inputs {{0,0,5}, {1,1,3}, {2,2,8}, {3,3,6}};

    auto procs = FCFS(inputs);

    //Sort based on PID before showing result
    std::sort(procs.begin(), procs.end(), 
        [](const process& p1, const process& p2) {
            return p1.m_input.m_procId < p2.m_input.m_procId;
    });

    displayResult(procs);
}
```

Now which guaranties do we want to preserve?

- `process_input` are simple data without internal constraints.
- `process_output` are simple data and seems not have internal constraints neither.
- `process` should have coherency between input and output: So no non-const-accesses to its members.

```
// const member might be enough in that case,
// but I prefer to avoid const members
// which make class harder to use (not movable, not assignable, ....)
// so only const getters
struct process
{
public:
    const process_input& input() const { return m_input;
    const process_output& output() const { return m_outnput; }

private:
    process_input m_input;
    process_output m_output;
};
```

Alternatively or in addition to getter, you might add `Display` method here.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have more encapsulation, then you need to apply the OO (Object Oriented) approach.

You want to put the data members and the methods, which operate on those members, in one class. So these methods can access the class members, since they are a part of a the class.

The function `void displayResult(const std::vector<process>& procs` and `void FCFS(std::vector<process>& procList)` are independent functions that operate with and access the `process` data members. They should not do that.

So I propsoe to overwrite the inserter operator of the process class. The process class "knows" how to print its data and hence should do it.

Same is valid for sorting. We overwrite the less than operator "<" and then the sort function knows what to do.

And also the function operator will be overloaded. Also this can operate on process internal data.

Unfortunately you want to have an additional sort criteria, so I need to add a getter for the proc ID.

Please see the revised code below. All data of process are protected. And we have only one read access through a getter.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>
#include <iterator>

constexpr unsigned int notYetComputed = std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max();

class process
{
public:
    process(unsigned int pid, unsigned int at, unsigned int bt) : m_procId{ pid }, m_arrivalTime{ at }, m_burstTime{ bt }{}

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const process& p) {
        os  << "PID: " << p.m_procId << ", "
            << "Waiting Time: " << p.m_waitingTime << ", "
            << "Turnaround Time: " << p.m_turnaroundTime << ", "
            << "Response Time: " << p.m_responseTime << ", "
            << "Completion Time: " << p.m_completionTime;
        return os;
    }
    friend bool operator < (const process& p1, const process& p2) {
        if (p1.m_arrivalTime < p2.m_arrivalTime) return true;
        if (p1.m_arrivalTime == p2.m_arrivalTime) return (p1.m_procId < p2.m_procId);
        return false;
    }
    void operator () (unsigned int& clock) {
        m_responseTime = clock - m_arrivalTime;
        m_waitingTime = (m_turnaroundTime =
            (m_completionTime = (clock += m_burstTime)) - m_arrivalTime)
            - m_burstTime;
    }
    unsigned int getProcID() const { return m_procId; }

protected:
    unsigned int m_procId;
    unsigned int m_arrivalTime;
    unsigned int m_burstTime;

    unsigned int m_responseTime{ notYetComputed };
    unsigned int m_completionTime{ notYetComputed };
    unsigned int m_turnaroundTime{ notYetComputed };
    unsigned int m_waitingTime{ notYetComputed };

};

void displayResult(const std::vector<process>& procs)
{
    std::copy(procs.begin(), procs.end(), std::ostream_iterator<process>(std::cout, "\n"));
}

void FCFS(std::vector<process>& procList)
{
    std::sort(procList.begin(), procList.end());

    unsigned int clock{ 0 };
    std::for_each(procList.begin(), procList.end(), [&clock](process& p) { p(clock); });
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<process> procs{ {0,0,5}, {1,1,3}, {2,2,8}, {3,3,6} };

    FCFS(procs);

    //Sort based on PID before showing result
    std::sort(procs.begin(), procs.end(),
        [](const process & p1, const process & p2) {
            return p1.getProcID() < p2.getProcID();
        });
    displayResult(procs);
}
```

Comment: What I dislike here: There are hidden dependencies between FCFS and some methods of `process`, are `operator ()`/`operator <` specific to FCFS algorithm or not (notice that processes are sorted twice differently, so natural order is not clear). And time dependency: does it make sense to call `operator <<` before FCFS algorithm (`NotYetComputed` seems a hack).

Comment: The << just prints the data of process. Whatever is in it. The '<' should specifiy some natural order for your precess data. That is up to the designer of the class. You can add any other "<" relation implementation. And the overloaded function operator calculates something with data for the process. Not FCFS. It does not even know FCFS. But you can also add a function with the name "doFCFS" or domething. Addionally, I would even create a FCFS class and contain "process" in it. But all this is very much dependent on your desired design. This is just an example of better encapsulation.

Comment: I meant that, as we don't really know the purpose of the class, we did some guesses for encapsulation which are not necessary correct (you consider those not yet computed members correct, but I don't; You consider computation from clock to belong to process whereas for me it would belong to FCFS (but now, I doubt)). Some of you guesses seems legitimate whereas others are questionable IMO. OP should know.